# works in local but not in production: Mongo nested findOne

Tags: mongodb, express, hapi.js

I have 3 collections: `trips, moments, media_objects`

Every `trip` has moments. The trip holds an array of `moment_ids`.
Every `moment` has a single `media_object`.

The client needs a complete trip object that already has the moments in them, and those moments need to have the media objects in them, rather than just holding the ID's.

The code I wrote works for me locally when I npm start, but once I push it to production (AWS bucket), they don't work the same. The moments inside trip do exist as objects, but the media_object in the moments are only IDs. It's as if the nesting only worked one level in production.

The following is my code:

```
tripsCollection.findOne({id: tripID }, (err, trip) => {                 

if (err) {
            reply (Boom.badRequest("Trip not found"));
            return
          }

 if (trip.user_id != request.headers.user_id) {
           reply (Boom.badRequest("You are not authorised to view this trip."));
           return
           }

 let fullTrip = trip;

 let momentsArray = [];

 trip.moment_ids.forEach((moment_id) => {

  // finds the moment based on moment_id
  momentsCollection.findOne({id: moment_id}, (err,moment) => {

  mediaObjectCollection.findOne({id: moment.media_object_id}, (err,mediaObject) => {

  moment.mediaObject = mediaObject;

  momentsArray.push(moment);
  // when all moment_ids are converted, return the full trip object
 if (trip.moment_ids.length === momentsArray.length) {
   fullTrip.moments = momentsArray;
   reply (fullTrip)
   return
}

return moment


  })

 })


});

});
```

When observing the network tab, I see that on production, it doesn't even call the API when I try to open the same route, e.g. domain.com/trip/22
Works on local but not production.

Comment: another thing to note is that when I refresh the route on that url, it does call the API, but the response is this error:
`You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.`

Comment: and another thing is this error, that only shows up in production: `registerServiceWorker.js:39 Error during service worker registration: DOMException: Only secure origins are allowed `

Comment: This cannot work anyway. You have async calls inside a `.forEach()` loop that cannot wait for their completion. You need to learn how to handle async calls correctly. Also most of this looks like it can simply be solved using [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and a single call.

Comment: okay so actually, after posting this, I did change the code to use $lookup. 

any reading recommendations for handling async call correctly?